# Errno -8 Servname not supported when using Paramiko, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

I'm trying to connect to a server via SSH by a Python script. Currently i'm trying out paramiko. I set up a public key between the client and the server so i don't need a password. I'm using the following code at the moment:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('192.168.56.102', 'oracle', None, '~/.ssh/id_rsa')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
```

But when running this I'm getting the error

> [Errno -8] Servname not supported for ai_socktype

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this complains about ai_socktype if you skip any of the parameters but don't explicitly name the parameters after the one you skipped. In this case the problem is that the parameter 'username' is the second parameter but is not 'username='oracle'. That is also why adding the port number fixes it (then no parameters are being skipped)

Answer (score 1):

You can just specify the parameters. Don't need to add the port number (if it's ok with the default one).

From the definition of [connect](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.13/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect), your example would look like this:

```
ssh.connect('192.168.56.102', username='oracle', password=None, key_filename='~/.ssh/id_rsa')
```

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by adding the port number as parameter!